# Filter records in bootstrap table with preset and selectable value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a regular bootstrap table. For some reasons I need a filter just for one field with preset value, so when table is shown, records must be filtered. But also, this value must be selectable from some list (like regular html select). And records must be filtered just by picking value, not by clicking some submit button.

I have already pursued this [filter extension](https://github.com/lukaskral/bootstrap-table-filter), but couldn't find out how to use it to satisfy all my requirements. I'd appreciate any help. Of course, the best way - show it with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a select dropdown with id "filter" and a html table with id "records", you can have this code show only the table rows that contain the selected value in the dropdown.

```
$("#filter").change(function(){
    $("#records > tr").hide();
    $("#records > tr > td:contains('"+$(this).val()+"')").parent("tr").show();
});
```

Comment: Not bad. But what the best way to do filter - like this one, or use always sql-query and select only this filtered data?

Comment: I would assume if you have a very large data set that needs to be filtered then it would be better to send the query to the server and render the result. In case of say, 500 records or less, you can load all of them at once and use some neat Jquery just like this to make it work.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try some different steps. If this solution satisfies me, I will tick your answer.

Comment: One more thing - I can't put this selector on one line with table toolbar. So it looks a bit weird, selector just above the toolbar. Is there any solution?

Comment: You will need to apply a few CSS styles to make it look the way you want. That is how things go with Bootstrap.